# Map, Search bar and result List in TableView, IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

I am trying to achieve a vertical split layout for iphone with 3 views.. Search bar, Map and Table with search results.. the data is  received from server in XML format.. I noticed foursquare has done something like this on their app.. I have attached an image which explain my requirement very well.. My question is that what should i do to get this layout.. i am not able to add map on TableViewController directly, is there any other way it is possible?

[image: Screenshot of Foursquare app]

thanks for helping..

Comment: Sorry for unclear question.. i want to know how can i achieve this layout.. i am not able to add map on TableViewController directly, are there any other ways it is possible?

Comment: Yeah, UITableViewController insists on the table being resized to full view. You need to start with `UIViewController`.

Comment: add UITableView on a view controller and also add map and search bar on same view. When you got search result hide the map and show tableView with search result

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I think i figured out another way, i can add map in a custom Table Cell for tableView, i am not sure if it will work fine, i will put solution if it works..

Comment: hey @locateneil24 I am searching the same from days. have you achieved it? Can you share the same with me? Thanks